# Ropevim not working: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pycore'

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, vim, rope

On an Ubuntu 12.04, with Vim 7.4, rope 0.10.2, ropemode 0.2 and ropevim 0.5.0

When I try to create a new Rope project (using the :RopeRename command), I always get the error
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pycore'`
I have tried with some other commands (:RopeMove, :RopeShowDoc, :RopeChangeSignature), and the error is always the same.

I have tried different ways of installing ropevim.
The first one was decompressing it in .vim/bundle, and running `sudo python setup.py install`.

I then tried deleting the files it had installed, and installing it from pip instead, along with modifying the PYTHONPATH.

But invariably I get the same error.

For more info, if I issue in vim a

```
:python import sys; print(sys.path)
```

, I get the following:

`['/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aeroolib-1.2.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Genshi-0.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SimpleGUITk-1.1.3-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/clonedigger-1.1.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx_patchqueue-0.4.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial-3.1.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/
local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Sphinx-1.3b1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/snowballstemmer-1.2.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils-0.12-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six-1.8.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyrg-0.2.6-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ropevim-0.5.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/
usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.6-gtk2-unicode', '_vim_path_']`

I tried it on my computer with an compiled vim version, but also on a stock Ubuntu 14.04, with the vim package from the repositories.

Would you know how I am supposed to install it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I tried to create a new rope project root.
When you get the question “Project does not exists in ., create one?”
you have to type 'yes' or it will be aborted with this error.